# Importing and converting Sql Server Latin1 into Postgres UTF8

Tags: postgresql, import, utf-8, character-encoding

I have some Latin1 encoded SQL Server tables that are being read into a Postgres 10.10 UTF8 database via foreign tables.

The problem comes from a couple of ‘free entry’ fields which have accumulated garbage characters which don’t translate into UTF8 and cause queries to fail in the PG database.  Using replace() worked for awhile but naturally new ones continue to creep in.

It is getting troublesome to keep tracking these down and add more ‘replaces’.  Is there any way within Postgres to bulk convert these strings as they are brought in to the foreign table?

4 attempts so far are:

1) 'convert_from' seemed obvious but I have only been able to make that work on defined strings, not field values.  Is it possible to make that work on random field values?

2) Changing the client encoding didn't help.  Does that even apply to this?

3) I also attempted to create a conversion as per https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-createconversion.html but I don’t know how to write the proper function.  It specifies the source string length.  If there isn’t a specific length, will this even work?

4) Perhaps built in conversions https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-string.html#CONVERSION-NAMES are the answer?  But I couldn’t locate any examples of how to use them.  I am not a real data base person so examples are very important.

Thanks

Comment: 1) you can try to use convert_from on a table column. For example `select  convert_from(c',UTF8')  from t;`

Comment: 2) yes this is not the solution

Comment: 4) built_in conversions are used by `convert(string bytea, src_encoding name, dest_encoding name)`

Comment: Can you give detailed examples of Latin1 garbage you have, errors you have, how you fixed them and how you would like to fix them ?

Comment: Thanks @pifor
For 1)  I’m currently getting ‘ERROR: function convert_from(text, unknown) does not exist.’  Could I have broken it somehow?

I tried switching to convert_to but that only yields ‘ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x96’

For 4)  After a few problems casting the strings into BYTEA, I was able to get it to the point where it gives a helpful error ‘ERROR: invalid input syntax for type bytea LINE 1: SELECT E'…’ so at least it identifies the offending character and makes them easier to track down.

Comment: That E' is how it’s representing whatever the hidden character is.  I replaced them before by exposing them in an FME workspace and then SQL Server replace() on each one I found.  (That was unclear in that in the original post, sorry).
What I was able to do today is use regex (\x{0000}-\x{001f} )in FME to replace all non printable characters with a blank space.  That makes me think it must be possible in psql as well so I’m going to try pursuing that angle.